# Why Angular Material mat-horizontal-stepper and mat-stepper, on following step, first (click) does not work?

Tags: angular, angular-material, mouseclick-event, angular-material-stepper

I have a weard problem with my `(click)` event, where second click is triggered in Angular code:

```
    <label class="selectLabel">Select floor tiles:</label>
    <div class="center row itemListedConainer scroller">
      <div *ngFor="let tile of getTilesFloorItems(); let i = index" class="itemListed col" 
      (click)="setTile()">
      </div>
    </div>
```

After debugging and many trials I figured out that this is related to `@angular/material/stepper`, and after going to the following step, first `(click)` does not work.

I managed to reproduce the problem in this Stackblitz: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uurs9q?file=src%2Fapp%2Fquestions-stepper%2Fquestions-stepper.component.html)

Please note, that when you click any green tile within first `step`, you will get `console.log('hit')`, even first time. And within 2nd `step`, the first click does not log in the console.

What is the reason and how to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue:

Change the `getTilesFloorItems()` pattern; assign your `tiles` to a field and read it from there in the `ngFor`. Otherwise you're creating 2 sets of `tiles` instances.

```js
export class QuestionsStepperComponent {
  public setTile(): void {
    console.log('hit');
  }

  tiles: any[] = [
    {
      type: 'tiles',
   ...
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let tile of tiles; ...
```

[Fixed stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gij5p1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fquestions-stepper%2Fquestions-stepper.component.ts)

Comment: Very good point. Do you have any idea why `ngFor` can not get array data via method, just need to be feeded from the property, on next `steps`?

Comment: It can get the data via a method but my suspicion is that when you go to the next step, the click handler stays with the previous array instance and requires 1 changedetection.tick (click in your case) to get it together. At least that's my theory :-)